# Is there a standard way to have automatic links to headers in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

On the [Bootstrap page itself](http://getbootstrap.com/css/), all of the headers and subheaders have a nice little anchor icon that shows up whenever you hover over the header; that icon provides a link to this header. I'd like to incorporate that into my own Bootstrap-based site, but I can find no documentation about it. Is this a standard mechanism in Bootstrap, or is it something separate they added to their documentation pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap's documentation uses [Anchor.js](https://github.com/bryanbraun/anchorjs) to add those links & icons. It is not part of Bootstrap itself.

Comment: Ah, excellent -- I'll add a Scala.js facade for that and use it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a custom CSS statement from their docs stylesheet:

```
.anchorjs-link:focus, :hover>.anchorjs-link {
     opacity: .75;
     transition: color .16s linear;
}
```

This brings the opacity of the anchors from 0 to 75% on hover of the parent element. You'd generate the links with your server-side app and apply similar styling in your custom stylesheet.

Core Boostrap styles are shown as being from `boostrap.min.css` in your browser's inspector, and custom docs styles are in `docs.min.css`. If you're not familiar with the use of your browser's inspector, now's the time. It's an invaluable tool.

Comment: Ahhh -- yeah, I'd gone in using Chrome, but missed the docs.min.css.  (Catching hover-only styles always makes me crazy.)  Thanks for the pointer; I'll have to decide whether to mimic that idea...